# Overlapping two rounded rectangle boxes together in Html for Email

Tags: html-email

I am trying to write a Html Code For Email so as to overlap two boxes together(they are not in table and I guess being in a table would be better, dealing with Emails). Or maybe overlap two tables so as to make the boxes overlap. The first box is containing blue color and the second box is containing white color which I would like to write texts on(i mean texts only on the white colored box). These boxes are rounded rectangle shapes.

Then followed by a rectangle shaped box below the overlapped rounded-rectangle boxes. And on this rectangle box, it will have a one-side box at one of the edges filled with blue which I will be able to write a few words on And also write on the main rectangle box too.

This is what I intend doing in general.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgs0H.jpg)

For the code given to me by Nathan, I tried creating a picture of top and bottom of the boxes and add a vertical lines body of texts to it, but all the four points didn't join together, leaving the whole box obvious that some junctions are opened. This is what I was able to do with the code.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4vBY.jpg)

But taking a close look at it, the points didn't meet. They are not joined at the the 4 points/corners.
If they can be joined then I think it is ok.
Thank you all. I appreciate so much

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's a cross-email compatible solution for this (read one deprecated solution here: https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/tutorial-css-fixed-positioning-in-interactive-email/).

I would try the following, making the top rounded area one picture, the sides a border, and then the bottom rounded part another picture.

```
<body>
  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-spacing:0;">
    <tr>
      <td style="padding:0;border-collapse:collapse;">
        <img src="top-part.jpg" width="100%" style="width:100%;border:0;" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="border-left:1px solid #000;border-right:1px solid #000;padding:0;border-collapse:collapse;">
        <p>Main content here</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding:0;border-collapse:collapse;">
        <img src="bottom-part.jpg" width="100%" style="width:100%;border:0;" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Alternatively, you could try making it all a background image, and consult https://www.litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-background-images-in-email/ and associated content.

Comment: Thank you so much Nathan. I appreciate. Thanks alot

Comment: Thank you Nathan. God bless alot!!

Comment: Will this work for all email clients if I am successfully able to achieve this?  Will there be a distortion of the pictures I would add? When i send to email clients?

Comment: This is cross-email compatible

Comment: Nathan, I placed a picture of what I entirely want to do. I edited my question and added some pictures. Thank you all alot!!!

Comment: Looks like there's padding in there. I'll edit code to show you what to do

Comment: THE EDITED CODE WORKED VERY FINE AND PERFECTLY!! YOU ARE VERY INTELLIGENT!!! THANK YOU @Nathan

Comment: Hello Nathan, Good day. I asked another question and I wish to get an answer to it. If you can be of an assistance, I will be grateful. It is based on normal html for web. Thank you